# Boot partition full and I can't purge old kernels

Tags: boot, apt

My /boot/ partition is full and I can't purge old kernels, I've been trying the suggestions here but no luck [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

```
dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic       4.4.0-71.92  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic       4.4.0-72.93  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic       4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic       4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic       4.4.0-79.100 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic       4.4.0-81.104 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic       4.4.0-83.106 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic       4.4.0-87.110 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic       4.4.0-89.112 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic 4.4.0-71.92  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic 4.4.0-72.93  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic 4.4.0-75.96  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic 4.4.0-78.99  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic 4.4.0-79.100 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic 4.4.0-81.104 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic 4.4.0-83.106 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic 4.4.0-87.110 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

sudo apt-get update suggests I Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

All I get for my efforts is this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

sudo apt-get autoremove returns

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic but it is not installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get autoremove`? That removes old kernels on my 16.04 server.

Comment: I've tried every suggestion ubuntu has offered, I've added the result of autoremove above

Comment: so I deleted using [sudo rm] some of the middle kernels, I'm guessing not the done thing, then ran autoremove and it is doing lots of removal at the moment. I would upmark your advice, but I don't have enough karma on this part of stackexchange.

Comment: Once that finishes, if your problem is resolved, please accept my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/911563/boot-partition-is-100-full-cant-remove-old-packages-to-make-space/912367#912367  You need to give the package manager some working space to do anything.

Comment: Or use linux-purge https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375025

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get autoremove`.

As you worked out yourself, you will have to remove an old kernel manually first.

After running `apt-get autoremove`, your boot partition should be much emptier. I personally have a root cron to do that weekly so I don't get into your situation.

Make sure you do an `update` and `upgrade` too to resolve the dependency issues, then reboot to start the new kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have run out of space and have half installed packages, apt gives up.  You have to remove some packages with `sudo dpkg -r xxxxx` to get some free space, then you can have apt remove more.